# Is ASP.NET MVC a viable choice for a large project?

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I want to use MVC for a big project, but I read in some website that this is not suitable for large projects.

Is this true? and are there examples of some great sites or application that have been written with this technology?

Comment: Please post discussions in discussion forums !! 
If you have any technical difficulties you can post your queries here

Comment: I don't think this should be closed. It's a yes/no question that asks for evidence.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We built the site you are browsing with it.

StackOverflow is a 100k LoC ASP.NET MVC site, and is currently <del>#66</del> #53 in the world for traffic according to Quantcast.

More in general, it matters much more *how you use it*.

Facebook is PHP based, twitter is Ruby based. Both are relatively slow interpreted languages, and yet, they work!

Comment: Facebook is not coded fully using php. it is using hiphop framework. only viewing side functions are handled by php along with javascript, ajax, jquery etc. all the logics, data calls, algorithms, are programmed in cpp, the main language in facebook. chat and updates(notifications) are programmed using comet(ajax push). php has 3rd rank after cpp and ajax, in facebook, on basis of priority.

Comment: @Skliwz i think twitter is scala based, it used to be ruby

Comment: Sure, when you have a billion or two you can afford those kind of improvements. The point is that platform choice did not block these sites from succeeding.